# Strange Issue with computer shutdown and cable outage

Tags: mac, router, internet, modem, cable

This problem first showed signs a few days ago. I was working on my iMac, and suddenly it shut off immediately without showing any warning signs. So, I powered it back on and my ethernet connection was not working (Wi-Fi was still okay on the same router). I found out there was a problem with an ethernet switch in this house. I unplugged that and plugged it back in and I had my ethernet connection working again.

Now today, my mac shutoff again. This time, the ethernet AND Wi-Fi was not working. I figured that the problem was with the router this time. So I plugged a direct connection from the modem into the computer. There was no internet, so the entire cable connection to the house was offline. Even the TV was not working because it uses the same cable connection.

So the problem is either originating from my Mac and causing the internet to go out OR there is some external force causing problems with the internet and remotely shutting down my computer. There are many wired computers in the house and only mine shut off while I was using it. Also, it is not a power problem.

I called my ISP and the neighbourhood is still online. This is only affecting me and I am not with TWC. This has noting to do with the recent outage. I am expecting a technician tomorrow, but I would like to hear what anyone here thinks of this strange issue and what might be causing it.

Comment: Your iMac powering off suggests that it _is_ a power problem. A power problem could easily affect your switch and router as well. Why are you ruling it out?

Comment: @Izam It might have been. I had a complete power outage yesterday for about 10 minutes after calling my ISP. Before it was only affecting my computer. The technician came and said that somebody broke into the cable box at the side of the house. The cables were loosened.